# C++: Segmentation Fault in the middle of printf, but only on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, printf

I'm writing a small OpenGL program on Ubuntu and Windows. On Windows it works perfectly, but on Ubuntu I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" at varying times during execution.

To narrow it down, I've filled the main loop with printf()'s to tell me when it crashes. But it's the oddest thing; it is often in the middle of printf when it crashes. For example, if I'm printing "Draw" it will often print "Dr" right before crashing.

I don't have any multithreading. I'm not passing any variables to printf; just printf("Draw"), printf("Step") etc.

The only way I could even think of for this to be possible, is if my shaders on the GPU were crashing, making the crash asynchronous with CPU activity. So I removed my shaders (used standard pipeline) and the error still occurred. :(

Any ideas what might be going on?

EDIT: sorry it took me a while to get back guys, I've been busy with school.

I located the bug - I was using a modulus function defined as:

int modulus(int x, int m)
{return x - m*std::floor((float)x/(float)m);}

Apparently the precision of float is not high enough to handle the outputs of rand(), causing this function to output impossible (negative) values. But changing my typecasts to double resolved the issue. It still seems strange to me that the crash was occurring out-of-sync with my code, but I guess it must have been a result of SDL using multithreading under the hood.

Comment: Post a SSCCE and a backtrace.  Possibly your `GL_VENDOR`, `GL_RENDERER`, and `GL_VERSION` strings too.

Comment: When this happens, usually you are going out of bounds in arrays

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in line 42.

Comment: Smells for UB around :P ...

Comment: @genpfault: I don't know what SSCCE and backtrace are, but I'll try.

Comment: @braindf: yes usually that's what causes a SegFault, but I've never seen it occur when I'm no longer accessing any data, i.e. during a call to printf with no variables. Have you ever experienced this?

Comment: Can you post your source code for us to take a look?

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is the smallest code that produces the problem. A backtrace is a log of the function stack at the time of the error.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was busy with school. I found the source of the segfault while attempting to make a SSCCE. SDL must be using multithreading under the hood, causing the crash to be asynchronous with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL implementations often do most of their work on a separate thread. It's likely that you've passed bad data to OpenGL, and the worker thread accessed it right at that moment. The backtrace of the active thread should make it clear whether this is true or not.

Comment: This is the answer, apparently SDL must use multithreading under the hood. I've edited my question to include the solution.